# MySQL table for single column

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

This is a question about database design. Say I have several tables, some of which each have a common expiry field.

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE coupon (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`item.id`),
    expiry DATE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE subscription (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`item.id`),
    expiry DATE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE product(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`item.id`),
    name VARCHAR(32)
)
```

The expiry column does need to be indexed so I can easily query by expiry.

My question is, should I pull the expiry column into another table like so?

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE expiry(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    expiry DATE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE coupon (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`item.id`),
    expiry_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY(`expiry.id`)
)

CREATE TABLE subscription (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`item.id`),
    expiry_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY(`expiry.id`)
)

CREATE TABLE product(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`item.id`),
    name VARCHAR(32)
)
```

Another possible solution is to pull the expiry into another base "class" table.

```
CREATE TABLE item (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE expiring_item (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY(`item.id`),
    expiry DATE NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE coupon (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`expiring_item .id`),
)

CREATE TABLE subscription (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`expiring_item .id`),
)

CREATE TABLE product(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY (`item.id`),
    name VARCHAR(32)
)
```

Given the nature of databases in that refactoring the table structure is difficult once they are being used, I am having trouble weighing the pros and cons of each approach.

From what I see, the first approach uses the least number of table joins, however, I will have redundant data for each expiring item. The second approach seems good, in that any time I need to add an expiry to an item I simply add a foreign key to that table. But, if I discover expiring items (or a subset of expiring items) actually share another attribute then I need to add another table for that. I like the third approach best, because it brings me closest to an OOP like hierarchy. However, I worry that is my personal bias towards OOP programming, and database tables do not use composition in the same way OOP class inheritance does.

Sorry for the poor SQL syntax ahead of time.

Comment: Each item can have only one subscription, one product, and one coupon?

Comment: I meant the relationship as in each subscription, product, and coupon has an item id. It is meant to be an artificial example.

Comment: Is there some explicit link between expiration of a subscription and expiration of a coupon, for example? Or for each type of entity, the expirations are independent?

Comment: expirations are independent, the only link is that the concept of an 'expiring item' is fairly common in this experiment

Comment: @shane Your first example is fine, your second is unnecessarily complicated (consider the process if you want to change an item's expiry date), the third is a classic subtype/supertype scenario. However, it has nothing to do with OOP, which is about communicating state machines, not about hierarchical or network data models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with the first design as 'redundant' data is still valid data if only as a record of what was valid at a point in time and it also allows for renewal with minimum impact. Also the second option makes no great sense as the expiry is an arbritrary item that has no real context outside of the table referencing, in other words unless it is associated with a coupon or a subscription it is an orphan value. Finally the third option makes no more sense in that at what point does a item become expiring? as soon as it is defined? at a set period before expiry...at the end of the day the expiry is an distinct attribute which happens to have the same name and purpose for both the coupon and the subscription but which isn't related to each other or as such the item.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* normalize "continuous" values such as datetime, float, int, etc.  It makes it very inefficient to do any kind of range test on `expiry`.

Anyway, a `DATE` takes 3 bytes; an `INT` takes 4, so the change would increase the disk footprint for no good reason.

So, use the first, not the second.  But...

As for the third, you say "expirations are independent", yet you propose having a single `expiry`??  Which is it??

If they are not independent, then another principle comes into play.  "Don't have redundant data in a database."  So, if the *same* `expiry` really applies to multiple connected tables, it should be in only one of the tables.  Then the third schema is the best.  (Exception:  There may be a performance issue, but I doubt it.)

If there are different dates for coupon/subscription/etc, then you must not use the third.